# HTML Markup within the Data attribute

Tags: html, twitter, seo

While messing around with Twitter markup i just found out that they placed HTML Markup within the `data-expanded-footer` and it looks something like this:

```
data-expanded-footer="<div class="js-tweet-details-fixer tweet-details-fixer">
    <div class="js-tweet-media-container "></div>
      <div class="entities-media-container " style="min-height:0px">
    </div>
  <div class="js-machine-translated-tweet-container"></div>
  <div class="js-tweet-stats-container tweet-stats-container ">
  </div>
  <div class="client-and-actions">
    <span class="metadata">
      <span title="12:11 PM - 10 Apr 13">12:11 PM - 10 Apr 13</span>
           &middot; <a class="permalink-link js-permalink js-nav" href="/****/status/****" >Details</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>"
```

Is this a valid HTML element (this attribute is child of a div element with class **tweet**)? Is it a good idea? What about for SEO?

Just tried to parse HTML from data attribute and it worked but there should be a single quotation if you want to make it work like:

http://jsfiddle.net/burimshala/crEXU/

And if you leave like twitter using double quotes within the markup and if you open the data-markup attribute with double quotes it does not work =:

http://jsfiddle.net/burimshala/crEXU/1/

How does Twitter parse this?

Answer (score 1):

`data-*` attributes are valid HTML5, see:

http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/
and http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html

It's main use is for data storage (in this case of HTML code). It all depends on your situation if this is a good idea, but it definitely serves a purpose. I use it often when I want to 'clone' dynamic content.

It's an 'invisible' element, so SEO should not really be affected, I am however, no expert on this.

Comment: I think you mis-matched the question, i know that is a valid one but is valid to insert HTML Markup inside a data-* HTML attribute.PS What about Quotes '"' ?

Comment: Yes, it is valid to insert HTML markup inside a `data-*` attribute. This includes quotes

Answer (score -1):

It's good declared, I would not say its bad for SEO because others SEO factors like Microformats for SEO (hCard, vCard or schema) all use HTML attributes.
As long your site is valid to W3C, and dont have any markup error (Check here): http://validator.w3.org/, than you are good with SEO.

The only small problem for SEO friendly this will be if your HTML markup code will always beat the website TEXT.
Remmeber for SEO always is better that minimum 51% of website to be Text, and others HTML atributes.